# How do I download a deb file for arm64 from Ubuntu Packages website?

Tags: package-management, arm, arm64

For example I find the package compiled binary on 
https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/arm64/libpython2.7/download.

How do I actually download the deb file?

I do see the warnings, I can not use apt-get because I need the binary for cross compiling on a stripped down Linux with no apt-get. I need the aarch64 binary.

Update: 
I did find the package separately on Debian's website https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/2.7.11-7ubuntu1/+build/9589511.
But is there a way to download from the Ubuntu Package page? I like the search system better.

Comment: The "search and download site" https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpython2.7&searchon=names ... ... e.g. 16.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpython2.7 : Click `arm64` to get to the download link page.

Comment: Launchpad isn't debian's website, it's an official Ubuntu website made by Canonical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ARM packages, take the path given there (`pool/main/p/python2.7/` in this case), and append it to http://ports.ubuntu.com, and pick the version you want from the directory listing on [that page](http://ports.ubuntu.com/pool/main/p/python2.7/):

> [image]

Also, Launchpad isn't Debian's site. It's Ubuntu's. That package is Ubuntu's.